# Function that checks if function executes successfully, otherwise exception. Possible in PHP?

Tags: php, function, method-call

I need some function that will accept a function as the parameter and will run it in try {} catch (Exception $e) {}. If it runs successfully, do nothing, otherwise, throw new Exception. That's something like function-checker, which checks functions if they ran successfully. Anybody can help me or give advice?
Thanks for any replies.

The function should work like that:

```php
function itwillfail () {
    echo 10 / 0;
}
check("itwillfail");
```

> Output: Caught exception: Custom exception text here, because it has been thrown as custom.
>   ("check" is that function I need)

What I tried:

```php
function check($func) {
    try {
        call_user_func($func);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Custom text here.");
    }
}
```

EDIT: More explained: I need to create function, which do the same as "try" and a lot of different "catch"es for different types of exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summarizing your question:**

You want a way to call a custom function from a string variable (which you have already figured out that would be via **call_user_func($var);**.

You then want that function to throw a custom exception error

**Confused**
What is not clear is the reason you would opt to not define your error handler using the set_error_handler function which would effectively do what your asking and set a switch statement to output different messages based on the error generated.

**Example**
The following example is not using a call_user_func but it effectively allows you to write how the error will be handled

```
<?php 

    function myerror($error_no, $error_msg) { 
        echo "Error: [$error_no] $error_msg "; 
        echo "\n Now Script will end"; 
        die(); 
    }  

    // Setting set_error_handler 
    set_error_handler("myerror"); 

    $a = 10; 
    $b = 0; 

    // Force the error 
    echo($a / $b);
?>
```

Comment: I'm very thankful about your help, but let me give you more understandable information what I need by editing my question. (Check Question edited later)

Comment: Check "EDIT" in question, please, for more understandable (I hope) explanation what I need.

Comment: Alright, got it. I've tried some other way, works for me. Thanks for help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not every function throws an exception when they fail. Many functions, especially ones that have been around for a long time, simply trigger PHP errors rather than exceptions.

To handle those, you would use a custom error handler:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

So you could set up a custom error handler that would intercept those kinds of failures and throw them as exceptions. The whole point of that function is to do what you're trying to do - handle errors in a custom way.

Comment: Thanks, I understand but that's not what I need. I want to create a function that runs another function as the parameter and checks it using try {} catch (){}. See "what I tried" for example, I need that doesn't work. Another example:
```php
functionthatchecksifanotheroneworks (function () {
return 5 / 0;
});
```